# Smart Pointers Destruction Issue - Unreal Engine 4.27

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I've been puzzled for a couple of days now, I'm switching over to using Smart Pointer instead of raw pointers, but every time I release the last TSharePtr in order to destroy the Actor it was holding, I'm running into an assertion exception when UE4 is trying to destroy the object...

Note that the object I'm destroying is created from a Blueprint as well.

Error:

Assertion failed: GetFName() == NAME_None [File:D:/Build/++UE4/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/CoreUObject/Private/UObject/UObjectBase.cpp] [Line: 130]

Code:
APointerReferencedActor.h (Class of shared pointer object):
class SMARTPOINTERSDEMO_API APointerReferencedActor : public AActor

APointersManager.h (Pointer Assignment):
TSharedPtr SharedPointerObjectPtr = nullptr;

APointersManager.cpp:
(Pointer Assignment)
SharedPointerObjectPtr = TSharedPtr(Cast(GetWorld()->SpawnActor(SharedPointerClass)));

(Pointer Last Reference Reset)
SharedPointerObjectPtr.Reset();

Repo Link:
https://github.com/Bisher-d790/UE4-SmartPointersDemo

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve] directly in the question as text, not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem that was happening is that you cannot use TSharePtr (shared pointers) with UObject classes, such as AActor classes.

The reason being that these are garbage collected by the engine, and cannot be garbage collected by smart pointers, as the engine GC system will block the deletion of the objects when the last pointer is reset. As I understood.

Source:
https://dawnarc.com/2018/07/ue4-tsharedptr-tweakobjectptr-and-tuniqueptr/
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/23497/view.html